# How do I pull in unexpected build dependencies of standard libraries

Tags: c++, ivy, gfortran, blas, build-dependencies

I feel somewhat ridiculous, but I'm trying to import the OpenBLAS libraries into a project. They were built with `gfortran` as the Fortran compiler. My early builds had no issue just pulling `libopenblas.so` in, but on another system, it's choking on `libgfortran.so` when I try to run our program, which doesn't exist there. My impression has been that this is a standard library on most, if not all, Linux systems. I could probably add a copy of `libgfortran.so` to Artifactory and let Apache Ivy pull it in, but it seems like it would make more sense to use the standard version if possible. Is there a good way to pull it in via Ivy when doing an `ant resolve` command if it doesn't exist on the system?

An alternate solution may be to statically link `libgfortran.a` in on the compiling system, but my attempts to do so by adding `-static RELATIVE_PATH_TO_LIBS/libgfortran.a` compile and link fine, but I still get errors when running said program on the system which lacks the library.

Thank you for whatever help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

If the executable file format is the "ELF" file format (default on Linux systems) you can use "readelf" to display the dynamic section of the executable:

```
readelf -d my_executable_file
```

It should contain a list of all shared libraries required. This is a possibility to check if the executable still requires this library.

If "libgfortran.so" is the problem and "libgfortran.a" is available I would rename "libgfortran.a" to "libxxxx.a" and use the linker switches:

```
-Lpath_containing_libxxxx.a -lxxxx
```

instead of "-lgfortran". I would not use the "-static" switch because in this case the linker also tries to link all the other libraries statically. The linker should automatically link "-lxxxx" statically because no dynamic library with this name is available.